# Reddit API: Return more than 100 results

Tags: php, api, reddit

I am using PHP to fetch the .json for a certain subreddit but I want to only pull the results from the past day (and this sometimes needs to pull more than the maximum of 100 results). I was thinking of just pulling the max 600 and filtering on `created_utc` but the Reddit API limits me to 100 results.

How can I pull the results only from the past day (or at least pull more than 100 results).

Here is my relevant code

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.reddit.com/r/[SUBREDDIT]/new.json?limit=600');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your only solution is to make multiple requests to the api.

So basically in your JSON: (example)

`"after": "t3_1oi5fb", "before": null`

`t3_1oi5fb` would be the fullname of a thing, refer to the documentation for more info here: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api

Remember that the API request limit is 30 requests in 60 seconds though.

Comment: How would I automatically find the last post (i.e. t3_XXXXX)

Comment: @Bijan maybe use search.json?q=whatever&sort=new - so basically your sorting all results and then take the first/last dependent on the sorting to find your last post.

Comment: can you please elaborate this abit... with example link on how to do